# How could i use webapi client libraries in .net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I created a Window application that consumes the Rest Webservice created with WebApi. My Window application  is in .net 2.0. So i cant use WebApi client Libraries to consume Rest Webservice. Is it possible to use WebApi Client Libraries in .net 2.0? If  not how could i call RestWebservice in .net 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use Newtonsoft

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/18/using-json-net-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx

and check this too

http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/08/02/net-2-0-support-added-to-json-net